# Windows File History backup size much smaller than Windows's own disk size?

Tags: windows, backup, history, sysadmin

I just set up "File History" on my Windows (Windows 11) laptop computer using Control Panel > File History. I did not put anything in the 'Exclude folders', so it should keep a history of my entire hard drive (?). My hard drive is 1 TB with about 600 GB filled. After hitting 'Run now' and waited for it to finish as indicated by 'Files last copied on ....' some time (perhaps about 20 minutes) later, I found the hard drive used for keeping the file history is only 30 GB, but my Windows hard drive has about 600 GB.

Does it mean the File History only kept history of a very small part of the files on my hard drive? Shouldn't it be close to 600 GB as all the files should have at least one version copied?

How can I be sure when the laptop hard drive fails, I could use this File History to restore all/most of my files?

Comment: Last time I used it, Windows File History only backs up certain directories. This is why I don't use it, it's very frustrating to manually add all the directories you want. The list of inclusions and exclusions will also reset any time you change disks.

Comment: @At0mic: I don't see a place to select folders for inclusion though, only a 'Exclude folders'.

Comment: @At0mic: So what do you use for systematic back up?